# correct format jquery selectors?

Tags: jquery

The code below relates to a simplified form with a number of repetitive sets of form fields. I'm writing some javascript to insert values in the form fields and then display the form fields, but struggle to get the right syntax for the jquery selectors - e.g., to use variables with the selectors. I looked at http://api.jquery.com/html/ and http://api.jquery.com/remove/ and some code examples like at http://jsfiddle.net/LYDuZ/, but still get stuck. Pls your help with respect to the right code for the javascript html() and remove() code.

Thank you in advance..

html code:

```
<style>
  .hideElement {display:none;}
</style>


<form>
  <!-- first set-->
  <div id="product0" class="hideElement"> Product <br>
  <p> productname: </p>  <div id="fld_name0"> </div>

  <!-- second set-->
  <div id="product1" class="hideElement"> Product <br>
  <p> productname: </p>  <div id="fld_name1"> </div>

</form>
```

javascript code:

```
for(var i=0;i<msg.nrofproducts;i++){

  $("#fld_name'+i'").html(msg.productname[i]);      

  $("#product'+i'").remove('.hideElement'); //finally show product
}//for i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Concatenate correctly, i.e: `"#fld_name" + i`
2. It seems that you want to remove a class, so use **`removeClass`** instead of `remove`

As such:

```
for(var i=0;i<msg.nrofproducts;i++){

    $("#fld_name" + i).html(msg.productname[i]);      

    $("#product" + i).removeClass('hideElement'); //finally show product
}
```

Comment: thnx all for the swift responses (!). With your suggestions the html() works fine now, but the removeClass() still does not - e.g., the browser does not display any fields. FYI: I include the sets of form fields within a simple html table structure; furthermore some other fields with other identifiers (within the table) also use the .hideElement class. Not sure whether that explains something??

Comment: Ah, I just saw an error in my code it should be `removeClass('hideElement')`, not `removeClass('.hideElement')`. The `.` is only used in selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to concatenate your ID properly:

```
$("#fld_name" +i).html(msg.productname[i]);      

$("#product" +i).remove('.hideElement'); //finally show product
```

Comment: Was just about to say that, darn you beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate

```
$('#product'+i).remove(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your need, but there was a issue in the condition. Should be :

```
 if( x== 1 )
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LYDuZ/45/)